# How to store login information for an api which requires Username - Password for the next session

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, session, authentication

I'm working with an unofficial n26 API (https://github.com/PierrickP/n26/tree/develop). The api requires the email and password to login to the account. 
I don't want the user to login every single time so I need to store these information somehow.
I can't find any way to get a session token or something for later use from the api. (maybe someone of you can find it??)

So my question: How do I store Email/Password for later use in a secure way?

```
const N26 = require('n26');

// Log into the account
const account = new N26('example@mail.com', 'password');
// Get the last 10 transactions
account.then(account => account.transactions({limit: 10}))
.then(transactions => {
    // Do something with it
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(account);` there may be an `accessToken` variable.

Comment: You're right! There is an accessToken. Sorry for asking this is completely new to me, but do I have to store it in my database and when the user comes back I just say account.accessToken = *accessToken from database* and I'm ready to go?

Comment: I'm affraid that the library does not support that. There's another library https://www.npmjs.com/package/n26-api which seems to be more up-to-date. Since it is essentialy a single file of 100 lines of code you should be able to change it slightly to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.passportjs.org/ Check out this package.

things to consider: 
 - json web tokens with refresh token 
 - API-keys